# ASP.NET MVC 3 - 404 When starting application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've inherited an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I know NOTHING about MVC 3. I've been using ASP.NET Web Forms though for 5+ years. When I attempt to launch the application from Visual Studio, I receive a 404. The browser points to http://localhost/Account/Logon. I've noticed that in my project, there is:

- /Controllers/AccountController.cs
- /Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml

I am assuming this is what should be launched.I've set a breakpoint in the Global.asax.cs and found that I am being redirected to this page via the following event:

```
void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_AuthorizationFailed(object sender, AuthorizationFailedEventArgs e)
{
  e.RedirectToIdentityProvider = false;
  HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Logon");
}
```

When I launch the application, I get a 404. I'm completely lost in regards to how to resolve this. I also don't know how to "Set as Start Page" in the MVC world. Can somebody please help me get over this hurdle? I just want to run the application. Thank you so VERY VERY much!

Comment: This is probably a daft question, but do you have MVC3 installed on your dev box?

Comment: scratch that, you probably wouldn't be able to build the app if you didn't. see, told you it was daft!

Comment: Here's where I found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877339/asp-net-mvc-beta-authorize-attribute-sends-me-to-wrong-action

Answer (score 2):

If you call

> http://localhost/Account/Logon

MVC, if you changed no routes in global.asax, is looking for

- a Controller Named "**Account**"
- the method "**LogOn**" in this Controller.

If you ActionMethod "Account.LogOn" returns a View, MVC looks into the **Views/Account/** Directory and try to find you **LogOn** View.

Lots of more informations:

[Asp.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc)

[Phil Haack´s Blog](http://haacked.com/)

[Scott Guthrie´s Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi dknaack, I noticed there is a method that looks like         public ActionResult LogOn()
{
  return View("LogOn");
} This method is in a file located at /Controllers/AccountController.cs. So I'm very confused why I'm getting a 404. Any ideas?

Comment: Right, methods in controllers are "actionMethods", they must return ActionResult or a derived type. Do you have the Views/Account folder and a LogOn file in there ?

Comment: I have a Views/Account folder. That folder contains a file named LogOn.cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

> I am assuming this is what should be launched

No, your assumption is wrong. In ASP.NET MVC you never access view directly. You always pass through a controller action which performs some processing on the model and returns a view.

So when you request `/Account/Logon` (assuming default routing) it is the `Logon` action on the `AccountController` that should be executed:

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Logon()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If such action or controller doesn't exist in the project you would get 404.

Before proceeding any further with the inherited project I would very strongly recommend you familiarizing yourself with the basics of ASP.NET MVC by following some of the tutorials here: http://asp.net/mvc